# Как вставить отрывок кода из с++ в код python?

Tags: python, c++

например эту часть

```
int main() {
    char **mass = new char *[8];


    for(int i = 0; i<7;i++) {
        mass[i] = new char[20];
        cin >> mass[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 7; i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j < 8; i++)
            if(strcpy(mass[i], mass[j]) > 0){
                char* tmp = mass[i];
                mass[i] = mass[j];
                mass[j] = tmp;
            }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        cout << mass[i] << endl;
    }

        return 0;
}
```

вставить в код python без открывания отдельного файла с кодом с++ (чтобы все было в одном файле)

Comment: по-моему такое можно вставить только  в виде комментария ;) Как, по-вашему, интерпретатор Python должен реагировать на вставки на другом языке (не важно на каком)? Но главный вопрос - зачем все это нужно??

Comment: думал, что есть другие способы буста с++ и python), но видимо такого не существует. *зачем это надо?* для таких дурачков вроде меня, которые нормально буст сделать не могут)

Comment: перепишите его на питон и вставляйте, и будет вам счастье

Comment: @ЕгорНиконоров если юзаете boost, то можете использовать boost::python для использования c++ библиотеки в python. Там ничего сложного, главное только скомпилить boost с использованием правильной версии интерпретатора

Comment: просто с python у меня запара.. иногда переписать просто не могу, а буст необходим

Comment: именно для этого и существует сообщество SO! :) Вместо того, чтобы приводить кусок кода на другом языке - опишите задачу, приведите небольшой пример входных данных и результат (в виде данных), который хотите получить и небольшую, пусть даже самую неудачную, попытку решения.